# Cache for offline access in WebView on Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a RSS, but I need to cache the previously loaded content for offline access. I found some ways on the Internet but none of them were clear nor solved that problem.

Ps.: I am using an `UITableView` to list the feed, and when you click on it, an `UIWebView` shows the original page with the news.

Comment: Hi, have you try saving the loaded pages content(HTML, CSS , JavaScript) in a database with their associated ID? or you can fetch the content of the news(Title,Date,news,author,etc.) and show them offline.